# Error in Rendering Sitemap in xml format

Tags: sxa

There is a Sitecore SXA sitemap enabled in the website, but I am facing the problem when trying to access it (example: sxa18/sitemap.xml), it gives the following error on accessing the url as show in image:

[image]

Comment: Please add your stack trace as text instead of an image to give search engines something to work with.

Comment: In addition to the stack trace, consider posting any Sitecore log entries that you think may be related, too. Diagnosing a null reference exception using only a screenshot is difficult. Is the sitemap configured correctly in SXA? Did you save/publish? Are other SXA features working as expected?

Comment: Sure , i will use text instead of image. Regarding the problem i just found this error occur's when you create a page in one language(fr-ca) and publish it without adding the version for other language(en). So when you access sitemap.xml it tries to find page url in both languages to render their url based on respective languages (like: sxa18/en/news1 and sxa18/fr-ca/news1 ). So when it finds page in one language but not other one it crashes sitemap page.